# How to build make 4.0 from make 3.82?

Tags: makefile, guile

I'm trying to upgrade my SH4 cpu packages. 'make''s version was 3.82.
If I want to upgrade to 'make' 4.0, it require to build 'guile'.
When I build 'guile'. It shows

```
$ cd guile-2.0.11
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr  --disable-static  --disable-error-on-warning  # OK
$ make
make: -n: Command not found
GNUmakefile:123: *** invalid syntax in conditional.  Stop.
```

The GNUmakefile line 123 is

```
123 ifneq ($(word 2, $(MAKECMDGOALS)), )
124 ifneq ($(filter $(ALL_RECURSIVE_TARGETS), $(MAKECMDGOALS)), )
125 .NOTPARALLEL:
126 endif
127 endif
```

I'm wonder am I falling into 'egg is born from chicken, chicken is born from egg' problem.

Comment: Note that gnu make 4.1 was released on 2014-10-05 so you should probably upgrade to that.  Check the reaLease notes— they might indicate build problems as one of the reasons for the new version.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Guile to build GNU Make 4.0. You can build it without it, just don't pass `-with-guile` to `configure` and you should be fine.

If you want to a build a version of GNU Make with Guile you can try first building GNU make without Guile as described above. Use that version of make when building Guile and then rebuild GNU Make with your newly compiled Guile library.

Comment: I'm trying to do this. `--without-guile`. And build make 4.1.  And got `Makefile:1280: *** missing `endif'.  Stop.`